# textless and text greater error

Tags: math-mode

I am using Overleaf for the first time and have no idea how to remove errors. My pdf was working properly but suddenly it is showing different errors and the pdf is not opening.
It is giving errors of textless and textgreater invalid math mode.
Overfull \hbox (1.53217pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 32--32
How can I fix these errors.

Comment: see https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-15

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you by any chance using `\textless` and `\textgreater` instead of `<` and `>` while in math mode? Hint: Macros whose names start with `\text...` should, in general, be used only in text mode, but not in math mode.

Comment: Without an MWE it is almost impossible to say. But have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70220/undefined-control-sequence-math-operators and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as? You may find an answer there.

Comment: Suggestion when you just don't understand the .log: When suddenly appear some error save the file, go back until the error disappear, then compare this old working version with you newer but buggy version. The mistake is for sure in what you add, removed or changed betwwen both versions.  If you cannot undo the actions, just remove parts of the document to locate the exact part causing the error.  Of course, taking care of no add new errors, (e.g., removing a macro definition or a`\begin`  but not correspondent `\end`, breaking the  environment). Annoyingly slow,  but educative.